# List all method parameters automatically to pass them forward

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, autocomplete, resharper

As the code illustrates, passing down parameters is a rather frequent task. Instead of writing them by hand, is there a way to auto-generate the list `isPriority, label, id, start, user` with Resharper, Visual Studio natively, or another add-on?

```
    public void TransformAndStore(
        bool isPriority,
        string label,
        string id,
        DateTimeOffset start,
        string user)
    {
        if (this.IsValid(id)) {
            label = this.Clean(label);
            this.Reposit(isPriority, label, id, start, user);
        }
    }
```

The list generated should be based on the method signature, listing all parameters of the method without their types, in the order they appear.

- Additionally, if the Reposit method were to use some but not all of the same parameters available in the calling method scope, as identified by parameter/variable names, then autocompleting that would speed up coding as well, and reduce RSI :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a class to store all the parameters so you only need to pass a single item around. Resharper can do this for you automatically by using `Refactor` -> `Extract` -> `Extract class from parameters`.

Also if you are always repeating the same groups of parameters, consider moving the methods that act upon them into the class too. Logically grouping the data with the methods can be a good practice. For example:

```
public class CleverName
{
    public bool IsPriority { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Start { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }

    public bool IsValid()
    {
        //Check if Id is valid
    }

    public void TransformAndStore()
    {
        if (this.IsValid()) {
            Label = this.Clean(Label);
            this.Reposit();
        }
    }

    public void Reposit()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting workaround, but even if I have only 3 parameters but I need to pass them on 10000 times a year then I would like an autocomplete, so I'm hoping to find an autocomplete solution. Upvote but not the answer Im looking for..

Comment: You could put these methods inside the same class. That way you don't pass parameters at all other than the top level call.

Comment: I understand, thanks. And the more parameters there are and the more chaining there is the more your approach makes sense, but Im still talking about autocompleting for lots of different unrelated methods with a couple of parameters that may only pass down once (no chaining).

Comment: There's almost certainly no way to autocomplete the parameters, but good luck finding one :)

Answer (score 1):

While it doesn't answer the exact question you're asking, take a look at ReSharper's [Smart Completion](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Coding_Assistance__Code_Completion__Smart.html). It will filter the available items for completion based on the current context, and is often really good at suggesting exactly the right parameter to pass through.